# ¿Qué se requiere instalar para usar wordDocument en Genexus?

Tags: genexus

Estoy tratando de **editar un documento de word desde genexus 16**, pero me lanza un error:

> No se pudo recuperar el generador de clases COM para el componente con
> CLSID {D4F1A949-0571-4CBA-B1D4-BB06564FE64D} debido al siguiente
> error: 80040154 Clase no registrada (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80040154
> (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). Descripción: Excepción no controlada al
> ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila
> para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el
> código.
>
> Detalles de la excepción: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
> No se pudo recuperar el generador de clases COM para el componente con
> CLSID {D4F1A949-0571-4CBA-B1D4-BB06564FE64D} debido al siguiente
> error: 80040154 Clase no registrada (Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80040154
> (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

**¿Qué se requiere instalar para que se ejecute correctamente la función?**
Mi código:

```
&File.source = &RutaWord
IF &File.Exists()
    MSG("Existe"+&RutaWord.Trim()) 
            &WordDocument.Open(&RutaWord)
    //      &WordDocument.RunMacro('DeleteEmptyTablerowsandcolumns')
    //      &WordDocument.Save()
    //      &WordDocument.Close()
ELSE
    MSG("NO Existe"+&Ruta.Trim())
ENDIF
```

El objetivo final es ejecutar un macro, pero ese es otro tema.

Genexus 16, compilando en .Net 4.0

Answer (score 1):

El tipo WordDocument está obsoleto desde Gx15.

Puede ver la documentación aquí:
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?2478,WordDocument+Data+Type